# Sort by aggregation in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Can you order by an aggregation in data.table?

I can do it in two lines as follows:

```
mbc <- flights[, .(miles = sum(distance)), by = "carrier"]
setorder(mbc, -miles)
```

But it feels like I'm missing something and this should be possible in indexing data.table. However, the following produces an error:

```
mbc <- flights[order(-miles), .(miles = sum(distance)), by = "carrier"]
```

I'm not really obsessed with it being one line, but more trying to make sure I understand data.table aggregations.

Comment: The `i`th part comes first in data.table, hence your second attempt doesn't work. Regardless, in your first attempt you could just do `flights[, .(miles = sum(distance)), by = carrier][order(-miles)]`

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg, if you post that as an answer, I'll mark as the resolution. I guess I still thought data.table would support that without a second index operation, but it works.

Comment: Perhaps, you may find the vignette [Introduction to data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html#enhanced-1b) helpful which explains the `data.table` syntax.

Comment: I've read through it before. I took a second look and it does mention the double index option, but there doesn't seem to be a way with a single index. even keyby param doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @David Arenburg's comment above, a double index works.

```
mbc <- flights[, .(miles = sum(distance)), by = "carrier"][order(-miles)]
```